# PostgreSQL CREATE SERVER with dynamic (non constant) options?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

Using `PostgreSQL 12` (or greater).

Is there a way to use SQL, functions, or properties etc to fill in `OPTIONS` when creating a FDW server?

I.e.

I want to do something like:

```
CREATE SERVER my_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS(
  dbname 'the_database',
  user CURRENT_USER,
  host current_setting('remote.host'), 
  port inet_server_port()::TEXT);
```

Any way to do something like this or configure servers/user mappings another way WITHOUT using fixed constants?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL. Compose a query string in your client programming language or using PL/pgSQL on the database server.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is indeed the solution.
Although an alternative others might be interested in is using [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a dynamic SQL like this:

```
--SELECT set_config('remote.host','pg.farfaraway.com',true);


DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
$_$
BEGIN

EXECUTE FORMAT('
CREATE SERVER my_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS(
  dbname %L,
  user %L,
  host %L, 
  port %L);
','the_database',CURRENT_USER,current_setting('remote.host'),inet_server_port()::TEXT) ;

END
$_$;
```